# Get AuditLogs for specific groups to know the users have been added to those groups in the last month

Tags: python, api, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to obtain the logs of the past 30 days to know the users that have been added to given group.
I'm using Python to report and modify different things and everything else has worked fine except this.

The first thing I tried was using the filter option as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/directoryaudit-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) like this `targetUrl = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/auditLogs/directoryAudits?$filter=activityDateTime gt 2022-10-08"` but I keep getting a bad request...

As it didn't work I moved on to another test: filtering by the newValue option nested inside TargetResources `targetUrl = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/auditLogs/directoryAudits?$filter=targetResources/any(x: startswith(x/newValue, '{value}')"` but got another bad request...

I'm not really sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Microsoft Example output

`

```
"value": [{
        "id": "id",
        "category": "UserManagement",
        "correlationId": "da159bfb-54fa-4092-8a38-6e1fa7870e30",
        "result": "success",
        "resultReason": "Successfully added member to group",
        "activityDisplayName": "Add member to group",
        **"activityDateTime": "2018-01-09T21:20:02.7215374Z",**
        "loggedByService": "Core Directory",
        "initiatedBy": {
            "user": {
                "id": "728309ae-1a37-4937-9afe-e35d964db09b",
                "displayName": "Audry Oliver",
                "userPrincipalName": "bob@wingtiptoysonline.com",
                "ipAddress": "127.0.0.1"
            },
            "app": null
        },
        "targetResources": [{
            "id": "ef7e527d-6c92-4234-8c6d-cf6fdfb57f95",
            "displayName": "Example.com",
            "Type": "Group",
            "modifiedProperties": [{
                "displayName": "Action Client Name",
                "oldValue": null,
                **"newValue": "DirectorySync"}],**
            "groupType": "unifiedGroups"
            }, 
            {
            "id": "1f0e98f5-3161-4c6b-9b50-d488572f2bb7",
            "displayName": null,
            "Type": "User",
            "modifiedProperties": [],
            "userPrincipalName": "bob@contoso.com"
        }],
        "additionalDetails": [{
            "key": "Additional Detail Name",
            "value": "Additional Detail Value"
        }]
    }]
}
```

`

Comment: Could you please provide the complete error msg that you got in both the case?

Comment: Also provide more code how do you call Graph API

Answer (score 1):

When i tried to repo in our side , its working as expected ,

API - https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/auditLogs/directoryAudits?$filter=activityDateTime gt 2022-10-10
[image]

As i can see the date you are written in query is 2022-10-08 , you can't query for more than 30 days , could you please try by changing the date to 2022-10-10 (if you are in different time zone , please try with date less than 30days)

Hope this helps

Thanks

When i queried with API - https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/auditLogs/directoryAudits?$filter=activityDateTime gt 2022-10-08
, the error message that i got  "message": "Specified argument was out of the range of valid values. (Parameter 'Minimum allowed time for activityDateTime is 10/10/2022 12:00:00 AM')".

[image]

---

Please 'Accept as answer' and ‘Upvote’ if it helped so that it can help others in the community.

Comment: Where did you find information that you can't query for more than 30 days? Could you provide some link?

Comment: yes , i added the screenshot in my answer , that's why i also asked you to provide complete error message , thanks

Comment: has the above query worked for you?

Comment: I don't have permissions for this in my tenant, but the error is self-descriptive. The limit is 30 days